I have problem with PHP facebook business sdk
I have problem with loading the images on creating Ad Creative
My code follows
    public function createAdCreative($ad_set_id, $adName, $primaryText, $description, $websiteURL, $file)
    {
        try {
            $ad_image = new AdImage(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
            $ad_image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = $file;
            $ad_image->create();

            $ad_creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
            $ad_creative->setData([
                AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $adName,
                AdCreativeFields::BODY => $description,
                AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => $websiteURL,
                AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $ad_image->{AdImageFields::HASH},
                AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/'. basename($file), // basename($file),
                AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_FILE => basename($file) // basename($file),
            ]);

            $ad = new Ad(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
            $ad->setData([
                AdFields::NAME => $adName,
                AdFields::ADSET_ID => $ad_set_id,
                AdFields::CREATIVE => $ad_creative
            ]);
            $ad_res = $ad->create(array(
                Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
            ));

            return $ad_creative->id;

        } catch (RequestException $e) {
            echo 'Exception ->: ' . $e->getMessage().PHP_EOL;
            echo 'Error details: ' . json_encode($e->getErrorUserTitle()).PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL;
        }
    }

Hash image is created succesfuly
AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $ad_image->{AdImageFields::HASH}
I tried with these 2 lines and without
AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_URL => env('APP_URL').'/uploads/'. basename($file), // basename($file),
                AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_FILE => basename($file) // basename($file),

I followed the official doc here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/ad-image/v20.0
as a result I see an error  "Missing Image"
How can I resolve this issue ?

public function createAdCreative($ad_set_id, $adName, $primaryText, $description, $websiteURL, $file)
{
    try {
        // upload the image and get the image hash

        $ad_image = new AdImage(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
        $ad_image->{AdImageFields::FILENAME} = $file;
        $ad_image->create();

        // retrieve and log the image hash to make sure that it was created successfully
        $image_hash = $ad_image->{AdImageFields::HASH};
        if (!$image_hash) {
            throw new Exception("Image hash not generated.");
        }
        echo 'Image hash: ' . $image_hash . PHP_EOL;

        // create ad creative with image hash

        $ad_creative = new AdCreative(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
        $ad_creative->setData([
            AdCreativeFields::TITLE => $adName,
            AdCreativeFields::BODY => $description,
            AdCreativeFields::OBJECT_URL => $websiteURL,
            AdCreativeFields::IMAGE_HASH => $image_hash,
            AdCreativeFields::CALL_TO_ACTION => [
                'type' => 'LINK_CLICK',
                'value' => [
                    'link' => $websiteURL,
                ],
            ],
        ]);
        $ad_creative->create();
        
        echo 'Ad Creative ID: ' . $ad_creative->id . PHP_EOL;

        // make the ad using the ad creative

        $ad = new Ad(null, 'act_' . $this->ad_account_id);
        $ad->setData([
            AdFields::NAME => $adName,
            AdFields::ADSET_ID => $ad_set_id,
            AdFields::CREATIVE => ['creative_id' => $ad_creative->id]
        ]);
        $ad->create([
            Ad::STATUS_PARAM_NAME => Ad::STATUS_PAUSED,
        ]);

        return $ad_creative->id;

    } catch (RequestException $exc) {
        // Handle API request exceptions
        echo 'Exception ->: ' . $exc->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
        if ($exc->hasErrorUserTitle()) {
            echo 'Error User Title: ' . $exc->getErrorUserTitle() . PHP_EOL;
        }
        if ($exc->hasErrorUserMsg()) {
            echo 'Error User Message: ' . $exc->getErrorUserMsg() . PHP_EOL;
        }
        echo 'Error details: ' . json_encode($exc->getErrorCode()) . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    } catch (Exception $exc) {
        // to handle general exceptions

        echo 'Exception ->: ' . $exc->getMessage() . PHP_EOL;
    }
}


Changes


removed IMAGE_URL and IMAGE_FILE because they aren't necessary

made error handling better to capture better and more detailed errors from the api

made sure that only needed are set when making AdCreative

added CALL_TO_ACTION field. adjust to your needs.



Thanks for your precise answer !

removed IMAGE_URL and IMAGE_FILE because they aren't necessary
YES I used it without it before.

Following your changes now i get the error like this
Exception: Invalid parameter
Error details: "Missing Image"
\n
P.S. IMAGE HASH CREATED succesfully

I tried fixing it in the code and updated the changes part. Also, \n doesn't create new lines in comments, just wanted to point that out

"\n" nevermind. It doesnt concern my the issue. Let me know please  Does it work for you ?
